# Eclipse Kepler change tree selection color or background CSS

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, colors, themes, eclipse-kepler

In Eclipse `Kepler` on `Linux Mint`, selecting items from a tree-view like the `Project` window is pretty straightforward:

[image: Eclipse Kepler Project Window Selection]

But on the `Searches` window, matches and potential matches have no background color when you select them. Hence, they become invisible:

[image: Eclipse Kepler seaches on Linux Mint]

**How to I change the color of selected text there?** I'm guessing it defaults to a system color, but for most other colors you can override that.

In Eclipse `Juno` this was not a problem, because the selection background color was, like in the `Project` Window, the same as the system default:

[image: Eclipse Juno searches on Linux Mint]

I *think* that in `Kepler` the system default background is not working *in the `Searches` window* because they forgot to implement it after manually allowing the contents of the tree view to have a different color from the system color specifically for *potential* matches:

[image: Kepler Search preferences]

Unfortunately, they didn't add options to change the *definite* matches and the *selected* matches color here, otherwise I would probably have figured this out myself. ;)

*edit* I figured out how to [change the background-color of the entire `Tree`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rap.help%2Fhelp%2Fhtml%2Freference%2Ftheming%2FTree.html):

```
Tree {
  background-color: #f00;
  color: inherit;
  background-image: none;
}
```

But I cannot change for the life of me the color or background of single items. At all. In the end, I'd like to change the background for the selected item so it becomes readable.

Just trying a bunch of stuff, but not working:

```
.TreeItem:even,
.TreeItem:linesvisible,
.TreeItem:selected,
.TreeItem:unfocused,
.Tree-RowOverlay,
.Tree-Cell,
.Tree-GridLine,
.Tree-Indent {
  background-color: #0f0;
  color: #f00;
}
```

---

*Note - In the `Kepler` screenshots I use the [Jeeeyul's Eclipse Themes](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jeeeyuls-eclipse-themes) plugin to change some of the hideous unbelievably terrible design decisions the Eclipse team made for `Kepler`, but this is unrelated. The font, the colors and the problem of the selections are the same with or without the plugin.*